# How do I convert values from a vector to a map in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I want to do something like this. Is there a stl algorithm that does this easily?

```
for each(auto aValue in aVector)
{
    aMap[aValue] = 1;
}
```

Comment: How is `aLabel` related to the vector?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a little... where does aLabel come from? Do you really want a map with all the values set to 1?

Comment: Im sorry it should have been aValue

Answer (score 17):

If you have a vector of pairs, where the first item in the pair will be the key for the map, and the second item will be the value associated with that key, you can just copy the data to the map with an insert iterator:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > values {   
    {"Jerry", 1},
    { "Jim", 2},
    { "Bill", 3} };

std::map<std::string, int> mapped_values;

std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), 
          std::inserter(mapped_values, mapped_values.begin()));
```

or, you could initialize the map from the vector:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m2((values.begin()), values.end());
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe like this:

```
std::vector<T> v;   // populate this

std::map<T, int> m;

for (auto const & x : v) { m[x] = 1; }
```

Comment: +1 Without more detail on the question, this is about as good as it gets.

Comment: Theres [boost::transform_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html), but I think I prefer this answer to using the transform_iterator.

Answer (score 12):

You might [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) into a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"I", "want", "to", "do", "something", "like", "this"};
std::map<std::string, int> m;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()),
               [](const std::string &s) { return std::make_pair(s, 1); });
```

This creates [`std::pair`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) from the vector's elements, which in turn are inserted into the map.

---

Or, as suggested by @BenFulton, zipping two vectors into a map

```
std::vector<std::string> k{"I", "want", "to", "do", "something", "like", "this"};
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
std::map<std::string, int> m;

auto zip = [](const std::string &s, int i) { return std::make_pair(s, i); };
std::transform(k.begin(), k.end(), v.begin(), std::inserter(m, m.end()), zip);
```

Comment: This is nice because you could use the two-input-iterators version of transform and zip two vectors together into a map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (auto it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); it++) {
    aMap[aLabel] = it;
    //Change aLabel here if you need to
    //Or you could aMap[it] = 1 depending on what you really want.
}
```

I assume this is what you are trying to do.

If you want to update the value of `aLabel`, you could change it in the loop. Also, I look back at the original question, and it was unclear what they wanted so I added another version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming items in vector are related in order, maybe this example can help :

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, std::string> convert_to_map(const std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mp;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> par;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i == 0 || i%2 == 0)
        {
            par.first = vec.at(i);
            par.second = std::string();
            if(i == (vec.size()-1))
            {
                mp.insert(par);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            par.second = vec.at(i);
            mp.insert(par);
        }
    }

    return mp;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back("customer_id");
    vec.push_back("1");
    vec.push_back("shop_id");
    vec.push_back("2");
    vec.push_back("state_id");
    vec.push_back("3");
    vec.push_back("city_id");

    // convert vector to map
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mp = convert_to_map(vec);

    // print content:
    for (auto it = mp.cbegin(); it != mp.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << " [" << (*it).first << ':' << (*it).second << ']';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very generic approach to this, since you didn't specify any types, can be done as follows:

```cpp
template<class Iterator, class KeySelectorFunc,
         class Value = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<Iterator>())>,
         class Key = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<KeySelectorFunc>()(std::declval<Value>()))>>
std::map<Key, Value> toMap(Iterator begin, Iterator end, KeySelectorFunc selector) {
    std::map<Key, Value> map;
    std::transform(begin, end, std::inserter(map, map.end()), [selector](const Value& value) mutable {
        return std::make_pair(selector(value), value);
    });
    return map;
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
struct TestStruct {
    int id;
    std::string s;
};

std::vector<TestStruct> testStruct = {
    TestStruct{1, "Hello"},
    TestStruct{2, "Hello"},
    TestStruct{3, "Hello"}
};

std::map<int, TestStruct> map = toMap(testStruct.begin(), testStruct.end(), 
    [](const TestStruct& t) {
        return t.id;
    }
);

for (const auto& pair : map) {
    std::cout << pair.first << ' ' << pair.second.id << ' ' << pair.second.s << '\n';
}

// yields:
// 1 1 Hello
// 2 2 Hello
// 3 3 Hello
```

The parameter `selector` function is used to select what to use for the key in the `std::map`.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another way:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int main() {
    using T = double;
    std::vector<T> v;
    auto f = [](T value) { return std::make_pair(value, 1); };
    std::map<T, int> m(boost::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), f),
                       boost::make_transform_iterator(v.end(), f));
}
```

But I don't think it beats range-for loop here in terms of readability and execution speed.

Answer (score -1):

For converting values of a array or a vector directly to map we can do like.

```
map<int, int> mp; 
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
    mp[a[i]]++;
```

where a[i] is that array we have with us.