# How to convert a array enumeration to map efficiently

Tags: c++

I am looking for an efficient way of converting a C++ array to a map according to the array index enumeration.

For example, if I have an array with

```
arr=[2,4,5,3,6]
```

I want to get a map like

```
[<0,2>, <1,4>, <2,5>, <3,3>, <4,6>]
```

My current implementation is like this:

```
std::map<int, int> mapping; 
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    mapping.insert(pair<int, int>(i, arr[i]));
```

Comment: I'm not going to close-vote it as a duplicate, because that would single-handedly hammer your question. However, does this help: [How do I convert values from a vector to a map in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912877/10871073) ?

Comment: OK- I'll close it, then.

Comment: The target for this question is incorrect, since it converts the vector to the *keys* of the map, with all the values being 1. This question is different, so I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

With the range-v3 library, you could write this conveniently, and quite readably, and it's efficient as well:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto result = input 
            | rv::enumerate 
            | rs::to<std::map<int, int>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MbdYcW).

Answer (score 0):

You could speed it up a bit by giving a hint on the insertion.

```
std::map<int, int> mapping; 
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    mapping.emplace_hint(mapping.end(), i, arr[i]);
```